# gulp-tslint not printing linting erros on console

Tags: gulp, tslint

Hi I am trying to run a tslint task using gulp on a small angular 2 app but it does not seem to work.Here is what I have so far:

This are is my gulpFile:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const tslint = require('gulp-tslint');

gulp.task('tslint', () => {
    return gulp.src("app/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(tslint({ configuration: "tslint.json" }))
        .pipe(tslint.report('verbose'));
});
```

To be absolutely sure I get errors I have set in tslist.json the following option: "max-line-length": [ true, 5 ]

When I run this task I get the following:

```
[10:29:54] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\InovationWeek\InovationWeek\Gulpfile.js
[10:29:54] Starting 'tslint'...
Process terminated with code 1.
```

It does not say anything about what linting errors it found just that the process terminated with code 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue where tslint was running into a problem with my configuration and was not actually performing any linting.

This resulted in the process teminating with code 1, but not returning any linting errors which seems to be same problem you are seeing.

My solution was to add a bit of error handling in gulp:

```
gulp.task("tslint", function() {
  return gulp.src(config.tsSrc)
    .pipe(tslint({
      formatter: "verbose",
      configuration: "tslint.json"
    }))
    .on('error', printError)
    .pipe(tslint.report());
});

// print the error out
var printError = function(error) {
  console.log(error.toString());
}
```

This meant that the configuration error that cause tslint not to run was written to the console and I was able to fix my configuration.